# Как суммировать значения в списке

Tags: python, массивы, список

Есть лист `a`. Значения `a = [10,15,12,16,9,5]`
Как получить `a = [10,25,37,53,62,67]`(прибавляя предудыщее число) возможно через np.sum(a) или типа того?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Первый вариант:**

```
from itertools import accumulate

ans = [acc for acc in accumulate([10,15,12,16,9,5])]
print(ans) #[10, 25, 37, 53, 62, 67]
```

**Второй вариант:**

```
import numpy as np

ans = np.cumsum([10,15,12,16,9,5])
print(ans) # array([10, 25, 37, 53, 62, 67], dtype=int32)
```

Comment: Можно же было просто `list(accumulate(a))`...

Comment: `A for A in X` — is always too redundant in favor of `list(X)`

Answer (score 2):

Вариант с изменением начального списка:

```
for i in range(1, len(arr)):
    arr[i] += arr[i - 1]
```

Вариант без изменения начального списка:

```
for i in range(1, len(arr) + 1):
    new_arr.append(sum(arr[:i]))
```

В одну строку:

```
new_arr = [sum(arr[:i]) for i in range(1, len(arr) + 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

При наличии питона 3.8 можно исхитриться и записать в одну строку: [песочница](https://tio.run/##FchBCoAgEAXQfaf4y6JZZGFU4EmihcFIQpmYQZ7eavd4PsXtdN3gQ84aCrNoSEgSLYmeRpJLsf6bMCkk1HhgDSx4v/izOQMsfefA7j446MilrpbCB@tiuVY5vw)

```
a = [10,15,12,16,9,5]
b = [y := y + x if i else x for i,x in enumerate(a)]
print(b)
```

Впрочем, код так себе.